# jquery each is only changing the first element

Tags: jquery, html, each

I am trying to have the inputs change there value depending on the click here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/x3fgg/

So i have different inputs like so

```
<li>
    <input type="text" class="mainfinput" value="something" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" class="ftext" value="something else">
    <input type="hidden" class="fbbcode" value="something else">
    <input type="hidden" class="fhtml" value="something else">
</li>
```

So i have the main input which will change value depending on what the user clicked. So if they click 'ftextbtn' then all the the main input value will use 'ftext' value. but at the moment its using the first li value with all the other li's. So what am i doing wrong

here is the js

```
$(document).on('click', '.ftextbtn' , function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('.link_list li').each(function(){
        var main = $('.mainfinput');
        var ftext = main.siblings('.ftext').val();
        alert(ftext);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you closing the inputs?

Comment: You jQuery code and selector doesn't match with HTML markup. Please post the actual code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x3fgg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x3fgg/3/

Comment: thank you, don't forget comments from Man of Snow, you need to close those inputs `/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are acting on inside the each has nothing to do with the each itself.  You never use $(this), so every loop is going to do the exact thing over and over again

```
$('.link_list li').each(function(){

    //to make use of the li each loop, you would need to do something like this
    var main = $(this).find('.mainfinput');
    var ftext = main.siblings('.ftext').val();
    alert(ftext);
});
```

[Including FIDDLE i updated from OP to work with above suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/x3fgg/3/)

Comment: Please dont use alerts - especially not in loops. Use `console.log()` instead

Comment: are you kidding me? we're obviously debugging here, and console.log throws errors in a lot of browsers that dont support it. Not to mention this came from his original code, who are we to say its not a requirement of his to have something thats blocking and/or alerting the user?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know only old browsers have a problem with `console.log()` and I'm pretty certain that this is not a browser compatibility. Edit: Ok I get that, altough I dont think that he needs the alert in the final site

Comment: and yeah i was debugging it :P i was justing checking that it was getting the value

Comment: @lukasgeiter - agreed, should not be in a final production site like that, and console.log does ensure it wont accidentally be left in.. but sometimes for quick debugging.. its just easier. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As [stated in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

`main.siblings()` will return a LIST of matching elements, and then `.val()` will extract the value from the FIRST of that list. That means that of all the siblings of `.mainfinput`, `.val()` will get ONLY the value of `.ftext` and nothing else.

Comment: so what should i just use var ftext = $('.ftext.').val(); ?

Comment: while this might be true about only getting the first of that list (not sure what you're doing with siblings) please see my answer for information on why you're not finding the correct mainfinput each loop.